# Files marked for delete, have actually also replaced on filesystem, would like to mark for edit

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, I deleted a number of files, which was recorded in an (unsubmitted) changelist. I then added replacement files in the filesystem, in the exact same locations as those that were deleted. As reverting them just fetches the old version back, how can I amend the changelist so that the files are as marked for edit with the new version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `p4 revert -k` to clear the files from the changelist without fetching the old copies back into your workspace.  Then just run `p4 edit` on them.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if you can do revert -k from P4V?

Comment: You can enter commands from P4V, using the text box at the bottom.